# Prestashop 1.6 / Thirtybees: how to call a feature to Product.tpl?

Tags: php, e-commerce, smarty, prestashop-1.6

https://github.com/thirtybees/niara/blob/master/product.tpl#L552-L559 shows how all relevant features are called to the product template - product.tpl . This is the code:

```
{if !empty($features)}
{foreach from=$features item=feature}
   {if isset($feature.value)}
       {$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
       {$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
   {/if}
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

Does anyone know how I just call Feature id 33, named Colour ?
My idea is that I could put some microformat schema codes round it, so search engines could know the colour. Maybe it's tricky and that's why I haven't seen anyone else do it, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need a test on the feature value:

```
{if !empty($features)}
    {foreach from=$features item=feature}
        {if isset($feature.value)}
            {if $feature.id_feature == 33}
                {$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                <span itemprop="color">{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</span>
            {else}          
                {$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                {$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
            {/if}
        {/if}      
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks you got me on the right track!
For some reason it didn't work first time, but web search for the vital part of code found me this thread https://archive.is/mgMgW where the last answer worked for me:

Comment: Close question if ok

Answer (score 0):

The ethercreation answer led me to this - the last post on  https://archive.is/mgMgW : or [here](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/563903-display-specific-features-by-id/?tab=comments#comment-2431848) Then I found that both work - thanks! It turns-out there's a limit to smarty {if...else...} loops which I have to learn about, but for putting tags round one line the idea works for me. With formatting, to replace part of a Thirtybees product.tpl file:

```
    {if !empty($features)}
    <section id="product-features" class="page-product-box">
    <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Data sheet'}</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table 
    class="table 
    table-bordered 
    table-condensed 
    table-hover 
    table-data-sheet">
    {foreach from=$features key=id_feature item=feature}
        {if isset($feature.value)== 33}
              <tr>
                <td>
                    {$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                </td>
                <td>
                   <span itemprop="color"> 
                    {$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                   </span>
                 </td>
               </tr>
        {else}
              <tr>
                <td>
                    {$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                 </td>
              </tr>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
    </table>
    </div>
    </section>
    {/if}
```